# Where to find dubbed and subtitled anime in English?

Tags: streaming-sites

I'm looking for sites where I can watch anime streaming. The episodes must be dubbed and subtitled in English.

Comment: Reference https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/922/102 - I don't know if it has all of what you're looking for, but these are (to the best of my knowledge) the current legal streaming sites.

Comment: Take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.

Comment: @Makoto Would it make sense to move this question to meta and close it as a duplicate of that?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the publisher, and sometimes even depends on the series itself.

For instance, the few times I've watched dubbed anime on Netflix, the subtitle quality varied depending on what series I was watching. Some anime matched subtitles to spoken word very well (albeit not perfectly) while other anime seemed like they didn't even try to match them up at all.

I've also noticed that the English subtitles tend to only have one version unless they also have one available for voice over captioning for vision impaired users. So if subtitles don't match the English dialogue exactly, they're probably meant for viewing with non-english voice versions.

If you're really picky about having subtitles that match English dubs, you may want to look into browser extensions, websites, physical devices, or phone apps that help assist with live captioning. These are meant to take spoken word and translate the captions live so they can potentially be more accurate. I've only used them in video conferencing apps though (such as Microsoft Teams and Google Hangouts) so I don't know how they would work on other websites, or what other tools are actually available with this capability.

As for streaming sites / places to get anime from, I would suggest looking at the [list here on the meta anime stack exchange](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/922/how-can-i-tell-if-a-site-is-legal).

There are also some non-streaming options to consider:

- **Your local library (Free!)** --
  Some libraries offer free access to online sites that let you browse not only audiobooks and ebooks but Movies and TV shows as well.You can also search your library's data base and see if they own any physical anime media (DVD/BlueRay/4K). If not, you can also try an Inter-Library loan for physical anime media (DVD/BlueRay/4K). Check with your local library to see what your options are.
- **Your Local store that sells DVDs/Movies** -- 
  Big chain electronics stores (like BestBuy) or Big Chain General Merchandise stores (like Target) may sell physical anime media (DVD/BlueRay/4K) in store or online.
- **Your local/online Japan merchandise store**
  These places may have physical anime media (DVD/BlueRay/4K). There are a lot of websites that sell anime; try googling some.
- **Anime Conventions** -- You can find physical anime media (DVD/BlueRay/4K) here too, but this is not the most accessible option due to possible need to travel and inflated prices.

The reason that I also suggest non-streaming options as well is because on most  DVD/BlueRay/4K cases (and entries in most library databases), it will say if it has English/Japanese audio and any available subtitles (English/Spanish/Chinese etc.).

With this approach though, it is hard to tell what the quality of the subtitles vs English voice over will be, but it is still an option.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for subtitles matching the English dub? Because as far as I know, that generally isn’t done; most English dub releases have two audio tracks, English and Japanese, and effectively one and a half subtitle tracks; full English subtitles for the Japanese dub, and a second track that only displays subtitles for the opening and ending themes (which are still in Japanese), along with anything else that’s left un-translated, meant to be played alongside the English dub.

Answer (score 0):

- Anime-Planet
- Crunchyroll
- Funimation has a YouTube channel where they post English dub episodes of their shows.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! We don't condone piracy, so unofficial/questionable/illegal scanlation/streaming sites will be removed without excuse unless it can be proven otherwise. That said, the question seems looking for anime streaming sites that are both dubbed and subbed in English, presumably at the same time. I don't these sites provide that service.